# I can't find the export tab in zwoptex

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

I am trying to use zwoptex for animation reasons for cocos2d so I decided to follow this tutorial, but i can't figure out how to use zwoptex. I want to export to plist but no such tab is found. Any help? It clearly says in the Ray Wenderlich tutorials that there is a export tab, but I do not see it.

Answer (score 1):

check File->Publish settings. There you can setup what you want, then press Publish, when you want to create atlas and .plist with description of frames

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.  Then I decided to pay for it ( $15 ).  There still is no export section, but when I choose sprites -> export it DOES now export the plist file and the sprite sheet correctly.  So the solution seems to be that you need to pay for it!